# Changing the size of Html.TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC3 application using the new Razor view engine but I'm having some difficulty changing a TextBox so that it is multiline. 
So far all I've been able to find via google is that I need to set the multiline property to true, but I'm not sure how.

View code looks like this.

```
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Body)
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, read the documentation. :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703535.aspx In your case, you might want to include `multiline` as one of the "HTML attributes" you can pass to the text box generator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could decorate the `Body` property on your view model with the [`[DataType]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

and in your view use the [`EditorFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402949.aspx) helper instead of [`TextBoxFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703644.aspx):

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body)
</div>
```

Another possibility is to leave the model as is without adding any attributes to it and in your view use the [`TextAreaFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703583.aspx) helper:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Body)
</div>
```

Personally I prefer the first approach.

Answer (score -2):

This is how to curve the corners of the textbox in asp.net mvc4:

```
@HTML.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.