# How can I change the size of a multi-line editor-field?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, multiline

I'm working on an MVC project using C#.  Right now, I'm trying to customize my views a little, and I'd like to make the text boxes bigger.

I followed the suggestions in this question to move from a single-line to a multi-line text field:
[Changing the size of Html.TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986442/changing-the-size-of-html-textbox)

Now I'm trying to resize that multi-line field, but I'm not sure where or how to do so.

Here are snippets from my Edit view

```
<div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body)
</div>
```

and from my model:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]  
[DisplayName("Body:")]  
public string Body { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would do this with CSS:

```
<div class="editor-multiline-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body)
</div>
```

and then in your CSS file define the width and height to the desired values:

```
.editor-multiline-field textarea {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I used the exact example above and nothing changed  the html.editorfor field's width.

Comment: I had to remove "textarea" from my custom .editor-multiline-field to have it resize correctly

Answer (score 16):

You can also use @Html.TextArea ou TextAreaFor

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text, new { cols = 25, @rows = 5 })
```

Answer (score 8):

In MVC 5 you can use

```
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.body, 5, 50,  new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

Works nicely!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using mvc and bootstrap
try this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Property, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 5 })
```

Comment: editor-multiline-field did not work for me, but this answer did! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To adhere to a previously created view  style, you can also do this:

```
<div class="col-md-10 editor-multiline-field">
```

Answer (score 1):

try

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Descricao, 5, 50, null)

in View Page

Answer (score 1):

I just wanna share in mvc 5

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body, 
                  new {htmlAttributes = new {@style="width:yourdesiredwidth;"}
                   })
```

or use a custom class