# Change text box size in the view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've create MVC5 App which generate from my model by scaffold the view and controller
currently the default size of the text box are 18 character and I want it to be 
5 ,how should I reduce the default size of the text box?

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.num, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nun)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Num)
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried without success with

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nun, new { @style = "width: 100px;" })
```

Comment: by size, do you mean the actual width of the box, or the number of characters which can be entered?

Comment: @wf4 Yes the width of the box ...

Comment: Is the css class col-md-10 determining the size of the textbox at all?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you can not do

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nun, new { style = "width: 100px;" })
```

is because `EditorFor` could contain more than one object. As a result, you would be applying properties to things which may be incorrect in the case that you may be setting an ID as well as a style.

So, there are a couple of ways in which you can style the boxes.

This CSS will do it for you: (you can use just 1 line or all of them which apply)

```
.col-md-10 input                 { width:50px }     /* <input> */    
.col-md-10 input[type=text]      { width:50px }     /* <input type="text"> */
.col-md-10 input[type=password]  { width:50px }     /* <input type="password"> */
.col-md-10 textarea              { width:50px }     /* <textarea> */
```

So for example, any `<input type="text">` which is a child element of `.col-md-10` will be set to `50px` wide.

or you can instead use `TextBoxFor` which will allow you to add an inline style:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nun, new { style = "width: 50px;" })
```

Answer (score 0):

In model do like this for **Nun** property:

```
[StringLength(6)]
public string Nun {get;set;}
```

if you want to change width then:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nun,new {style="width:100px" })
```

Comment: Thanks but this is restrict  the number of the characters you can put in the text box and not the size of it...

Comment: you doint want to restrict user on 6 characters?

Comment: then see the updated version of answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextBoxFor`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nun, new { @style = "width: 100px;" })
```

Check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119221/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-a-multi-line-editor-field) . If you dont want to use `TextBoxFor` instead of `EditorFor`