# MVC3 Razor Html.TextBoxFor: Can I make it Multi-Line like TextAreaFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, textbox, razor, textarea, multiline

I've already seen this post: [Changing the size of Html.TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986442/changing-the-size-of-html-textbox)

But I cannot change to `Html.TextAreaFor()` because it does not have an attribute for me to set a dynamic default value (I am making an edit page that I want to dynamically fill in the fields of the current data which can then be modified). I also can't seem to get the EditorFor to work even if I change to `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` in my viewmodel (all it does it seem to change to textboxfor and my default values do not show up).

My edit view takes in a viewmodel containing two models, an empty form (`OfferForm`) to be filled with the onscreen fields, and the `offer` model containing the current data. I want to have textfields for the `OfferForm`, and dynamically fill them with the contents of the `offer` model's data.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="InLine">
                    <div class="InLine editor-label-container">
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OfferForm.Description)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="InLine editor-field-container">
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OfferForm.Description, new { @Value = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Offer.Description)})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Offer.Description)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="InLine">
                    <div class="InLine editor-label-container">
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OfferForm.SMSText)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="InLine editor-field-container">
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OfferForm.SMSText, new { @Value = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Offer.SmsText)})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Offer.SmsText)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Is there a way to set a "`multiline`" attribute in the `Html.TextBoxFor()`?

Comment: Why are you looking to set the `value` property. In the case of the text area the `value` is what's contained within the html elements. As for your examples you don't need to set the value property for either the `TextBoxFor` or the `TextAreaFor` as when you use the `Html.*` helper it automatically populates the value.

Comment: @BuildStarted - The reason I need to set the `Value` is because the value is not populated from the Model for which I am using `TextBoxFor` or `TextAreaFor` (ie. the blank OfferForm). Instead, it is populated from a second Model in my ViewModel (ie. the Offer).

Comment: Ah, I see. very subtle naming difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to proceed would be to create an Html extension method like the following

```
public static class HtmlTextAreaExtensions {

    public static IHtmlString TextAreaFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, int rows, int cols, object htmlAttributes = null, string Value = null) {
        return TextAreaFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression, rows, cols, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes), Value);
    }

    public static IHtmlString TextAreaFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, int rows, int cols, IDictionary<string, string> htmlAttributes = null, string Value = null) {
        var modelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

        string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);

        Dictionary<string, object> rowsAndColumns = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (rows > 0) {
            rowsAndColumns.Add("rows", rows.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        } else {
            rowsAndColumns.Add("rows", "5");
        }
        if (cols > 0) {
            rowsAndColumns.Add("cols", cols.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        } else {
            rowsAndColumns.Add("cols", "20");
        }
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("textarea");
        tagBuilder.GenerateId(fullName);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes, true);
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(rowsAndColumns, false);  // Only force explicit rows/cols
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", fullName, true);

        // If there are any errors for a named field, we add the CSS attribute.
        ModelState modelState;
        if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fullName, out modelState) && modelState.Errors.Count > 0) {
            tagBuilder.AddCssClass(HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName);
        }

        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name));

        string value;
        if (Value != null) {
            value = Value;
        } else if (modelState != null && modelState.Value != null) {
            value = modelState.Value.AttemptedValue;
        } else if (modelMetadata.Model != null) {
            value = modelMetadata.Model.ToString();
        } else {
            value = String.Empty;
        }

        // The first newline is always trimmed when a TextArea is rendered, so we add an extra one
        // in case the value being rendered is something like "\r\nHello".
        tagBuilder.SetInnerText(Environment.NewLine + value);

        return new HtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}
```

You could then call it:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(f => f.ModelProperty, Value=f.SomeOtherModelProperty)
```

It only supports basic features and what not. The actual tag generation was pulled from Mvc3 source with slight changes to support passing the value in. This should work for most cases but you might need to add more overrides. This isn't very...clean but should get you going. :)

To get the extension to show up inside your razor views you edit the `Web.config` **within the Views directory** and add the **namespace** (not the class name) where you put this class. It should then show up in intellisense.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need, however I've never done an Html.Helper extension before. I looked at this page [How To Create Html Helpers](http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/) but does the extension just go in the Models folder? I added the namespace from my class to the web.config. If you're sure that is how it should be called, I keep getting the error: `The name 'Value' does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: This isn't an html helper but rather an extension. I've updated the answer with the full class and a quick quip as to how to get it to work in views.

Comment: You're the man! Thank you so much. It worked just like I wanted :). Here is how I had to call it after adding the namespace to the web.config inside the views directory: `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.OfferForm.Description, 5, 1, null, Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Offer.Description).ToString())`

Comment: If you're not going to use the `htmlAttributes` you can remove it. I use them all the time so I wanted to make sure it was there for others.

Answer (score 3):

You have to realize that HTML elements are *not* windows controls, they just map to them somewhat.

HTML elements have to be cross platform, and there is no guarantee that a textarea is just a multi-line textbox on all platforms, so as far as HTML is concerned a textbox and a textarea are two different things.

So the answer is no, because there is no multiline attribute for a textbox in HTML.

Comment: So there is no way to have a multi-line textbox or a textarea with default value parameter? I can get an editorfor to do what I want if I use it as an EditorFor(Offer), however I want an EditorFor(OfferForm), but I want it to contain the Offer information, so I cannot do that. Am I out of luck?

Comment: @Evan Layman - I don't know about the default value, I am simply answering your question about a multi-line textbox.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your answer, I just wish there were some way to get the html elements to appear as I'd like :)