# TextBoxFor Mulitline

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi people I have been at this for like 5 days and could not find a solution am trying to get this to go on multi line `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Headline, new { style = "width: 400px; Height: 200px;"})`but I have had no luck.

The following is what I tried:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor.Multiline (does not work)
```

I have put Multiline on the end of new and that has not worked. What is the simplest way of doing this.

Thank You I am using MVC3 C#

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740890/mvc3-razor-html-textboxfor-can-i-make-it-multi-line-like-textareafor

Comment: That is to complex, for what i want That is why I have stated "What is the simplest way of doing this"

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could use a `TextAreaFor` helper:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(
    model => model.Headline, 
    new { style = "width: 400px; height: 200px;" }
)
```

but a much better solution is to decorate your `Headline` view model property with the `[DataType]` attribute specifying that you want it to render as a `<textarea>`:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Headline { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

and then use the `EditorFor` helper:

```
<div class="headline">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Headline)
</div>
```

and finally in your CSS file specify its styling:

```
div.headline {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Now you have a proper separation of concerns.

Comment: The textarea is going to be what you're wanting for a multi-line form field. The resizing is something that happens with different browsers, both Firefox and Chrome will allow that to happen where as IE will not.

Comment: @Darin Thanks Darin for explaining this minute thing ,Before this I havent used the '[Datatype(DataType.MultilineText)]' Annotation for textarea Thanks.

Comment: I know this is an age-old post, but it's the top search result for "razor multiline textboxfor" and I just wanted to add that the CSS selector is wrong and should be `div.headline textarea`